# VirtualBox creates lots of .vdi files. Can I remove them?

Tags: virtualbox

I noticed my hard drive filling up and it is due to huge .vdi files being generated by virtualbox. I only use one virtual machine and rarely take snapshots to save state but I see there are about 12 .vdi files that exist all with names like "{cbf0c2c4-bc80-4022-a1d0-26866830d18a}.vdi". Any idea what these are and how to get rid of them.

Comment: Nice. Down voting a question with no feedback. That sounds like that is in line with the Q&A knowledge sharing nature of this community. Good job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a snapshot is taken or state is saved due to your host shutdown not only is a snapshot file created but also auto generated .vdi files that represent differences in the original image to the snapshot image. If you delete a snapshot then these diff .vdi files also are removed.